# Gridview PageIndexChanging event not firing

Tags: asp.net, gridview, user-controls, page-index-changed

I hav a gridview inside a usercontrol

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdMissingFilterData" runat="server"   AllowPaging="True" Width="100%"
                        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None"
                        PageSize="30" OnPageIndexChanging="grdMissingFilterData_PageIndexChanging">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Varenummer" HeaderText="Varenummer"   ItemStyle-Width="25%" >
                            <ItemStyle Width="25%" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Varenavn" HeaderText="Varenavn"  ItemStyle-Width="15%" >
                            <ItemStyle Width="15%" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Producentvarenummer" HeaderText="Producent varenummer"  ItemStyle-Width="15%" >
                            <ItemStyle Width="15%" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                        </Columns>
                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altrow" />
                        <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" PageButtonCount="50" />
                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                            There is no data available to display!
                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
   <PagerStyle CssClass="pager" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

and code in postback

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {  
        BindData(); 
    }
```

then i had a PageIndexChanging  event which never fires when i click on paging.

```
 protected void grdMissingFilterData_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grdMissingFilterData.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindData();
}
```

can any one give me any possible reasons?

Comment: Have you stepped through your code?

Comment: @codingbiz:yes, i had put break point and checked everything.when i click paging the only place code execution goes is page load event

Comment: Try taking your pager settings out and add page size attribute to gridview definition. On the page you are hosting the control are there any field validations required? This could be blocking the submission of your form to the server.

Comment: @LairdStreak:removing the PagerSettings never made any change in the problem

Comment: The code looks all good try removing the "grdMissingFilterData_PageIndexChanging" from the grid and binding the event in the page_preinit looks something like this grdMissingFilterData.grdMissingFilterData_PageIndexChanging += grdMissingFilterData_PageIndexChanging();

Comment: What did you determine was your problem on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be probably an issue with your user control not about gridview.
Focus on that part